# How to generate a specific Nested JSON using python

Tags: python, json, nested

Unable to produce specific group & subgroup in JSON using Python

I am trying to generate nested JSON using Python Pandas. But, somehow not able to figure it out as how the sub-grouping works or rather I can generate it. Not sure how to pack the subgroup first & then going for the group.

Is there any built-in function in python or pandas or any relevant package of Python that can do the same without writing lots of code?

What I have written is below:

```
j = (df.groupby(['empno', 'work_id'], as_index=False)
         .apply(lambda x: x[['status_id', 'type', 'languageId', 'language',
                             'email', 'game_name', 'experience_level', 'CellNo'
                             ]].to_dict('r'))
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={0: 'workPostDetails'})
         .to_json(orient='records'))

    print("JSON::")
    print(j)
```

**Sample Data:**

```
empno   work_id     status_id   type    languageId  Language    send_by         recived_by      game_name       experience_level
-----   ----------  ----------  -----   ----------- ---------   ---------       ----------      -------------   -----------------
0017    X123        2101        email   1           All         a@abc.com       b@xyz.com       C++             Expert
0017    X123        2103        phone   1           All         +1 9282828282   +1 9383838383   A++             Intermediate
```

**Expected JSON:**

```
{     
   "empno": "0017",     
   "work_id": "X123",     
   "workPostDetails": {         
                    "workDetails": [             
                                     {                 
                                        "status_id": "2101",                 
                                        "type": "email",                 
                                        "languageId": "1",                 
                                        "language": "All-Read-Write",                 
                                        "send_by": {                     
                                                      "email": "a@abc.com"                 
                                                   },                 
                                        "recived_by": [                     
                                                      {                         
                                                        "email": "b@xyz.com"                     
                                                      }                 
                                                    ],                 
                                        "skillDetails": [                     
                                                          {                         
                                                            "game_name": "EA Sports",                         
                                                            "experience_level": "Expert"                     
                                                          }                
                                                        ]             
                                     },             
                                     {                 
                                        "status_id": "2103",                 
                                        "type": "sms",                 
                                        "languageId": "2",                 
                                        "language": "All-Read",                 
                                        "send_by": {                     
                                                     "CellNo": "+1 9282828282"                 
                                                   },                 
                                        "recived_by": [                     
                                                        {                         
                                                          "CellNo": "+1 9383838383"                     
                                                        }                 
                                                      ],                 
                                        "skillDetails": [                     
                                                          {                         
                                                            "game_name": "Candy Crush",                         
                                                            "experience_level": "Intermediate"                     
                                                          }           
                                                        ]             
                                     }         
                                  ]     
                 } 
}
```

Comment: Just one correction. The game name in the sample data is showing as A++ & C++. But, the JSON contains actual game name. You can take any sample & provide the approach. Appreciate your time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could first prepare your dataframe by adapting the columns, and then iterate the GroupBy object. It would give:

```
# act on a copy to preserve original data
df2 = df.copy()

# prepare columns
df2[['send_by', 'recived_by']] = df[['send_by', 'recived_by']].apply(
    lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: { 'email': y} if '@' in y else {'CellNo':y}))
df2['skillDetails'] = df2.apply(lambda x: {k: x[k]
                       for k in ('game_name','experience_level')}, axis=1)
df2.drop(columns=['game_name','experience_level'], inplace=True)

# generate the json string
j = pandas.DataFrame(((name[0], name[1],
           val.loc(axis=1)['status_id':].to_dict('r'))
          for name, val in df2.groupby(['empno', 'work_id'])),
         columns = ['empno', 'work_id', 'workPostDetail']).to_json(orient ='records')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, it is close to the solution that I am looking for. The only thing is missing compared to what is my expected output is -> "workDetails":

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final version -

```
df2 = df.copy()

# prepare columns
df2[['send_by', 'recived_by']] = df[['send_by', 'recived_by']].apply(
lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: { 'email': y} if '@' in y else {'CellNo':y}))
df2['skillDetails'] = df2.apply(lambda x: {k: x[k]
                   for k in ('game_name','experience_level')}, axis=1)
df2.drop(columns=['game_name','experience_level'], inplace=True)
df2['workDetails'] = df2.apply(lambda x1: {k1: x1[k1]
                   for k1 in 
('status_id','type','languageId','Language','send_by','recived_by','skillDetails')}, axis=1)
df2.drop(columns=['status_id','type','languageId', 'Language', 'send_by', 'recived_by', 'skillDetails'], inplace=True)
# generate the json string

j = p.DataFrame(((name[0], name[1],
       val.loc(axis=1)['workDetails':].to_dict('r'))
      for name, val in df2.groupby(['empno', 'work_id'])),
     columns = ['empno', 'work_id', 'workPostDetail']).to_json(orient ='records')
```

Thanks guys!